# associate a specific index to a vector

Tags: r, vector

Can I associate an index to a vector that is maintained and that I can retrieve by a second vector?

```
V1<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

I want to associate an index something similar to:

```
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
 1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Then by a second vector

```
V2<-c("b", "c", "f")
```

I should get integers `2, 3, 6`

I know I can create a data frame with two columns `ID=V1 and ixd= 1:length(V1)`and subset by `V2`

I am wondering if there is a faster way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a named vector, i.e.

```
v1 <- setNames(seq(6), letters[1:6])

#then,

v1[names(v1) %in% c('b', 'c', 'f') ]
#b c f 
#2 3 6
```

Note that while a named vector also has names for its values, it is still numeric

Or as @jogo suggests, simply

```
v1[c('b', 'c', 'f')]
#b c f 
#2 3 6
```

Comment: `v1[c('b', 'c', 'f')]`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide an alternative way:

`V1 <- 1:6
names(V1) <- letters[1:6]   # Attach names to your list
V2 <- letters[seq(2,6,2)]   # c("b","d","f")
V1[V2]`

This gives me

```
b d f
2 4 6
```

Comment: Output-wise, nothing. But some code can be easier to read/understand than others. For instance, I show that you can attach names to a list after declaring the list (don't need to do it concurrent). And that you can index a list by name directly. Perhaps these are useful to the OP.